# time is changing while we use react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-datepicker

> i have selected 12:00 Pm in datepicker and i also console log it .... it shows Thu Jul 09 2020 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) which is right time.
> but when i click on save then it sends wrong time (2020-07-09T06:30:00.454Z).
> It sends 5 and half hour less to the time which user selected.
> It should send (2020-07-09T012:00:00.454Z)----Expected Behaviour
> i dont know what is the issue and how to fixx this
> my code

```
 <DatePicker
        selected={new Date(value)}
        onChange={(e) => setFieldValue(field.name, e)}
        className={classes.datePicker}
        todayButton="Today"
        {...rest}
      />
```

I need to pass exact same time which user has selected .
I think this issue occurs due to timezone or utc etc . so please help

Comment: It is the right behavior. Ideally the date and time should be stored as UTC format. You can use `toLocale*` methods to convert UTC to user's timezone while displaying it.

Comment: @MjZac displaying is actually not the problem but while storing in database the wrong time is saved like user has selected 12:00 PM so it should store 12:00 pm not 6:30AM.

Comment: @MjZac i used to stick to server time only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem with javascript. I usually write a "fix timezone offset" function ald call this function before I send my code to the backend:

```
export const fixTimezoneOffset = (date: Date) : string => {
  if(!date) return "";
  return new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toJSON();
}
```

And you call it like this: `fixTimezoneOffset(my_date)`

Disclaimer: fixTimezoneOffset returns a string which will automatically be computed into a datetime object in your backend. Call fixTimezoneOffset only once and not multiple times!!

Comment: I used fixTimezoneOffset function but it always returns time as 00:00:00(2020-07-16T00:00:00.000Z)
eg Thu Jul 16 2020 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard TIme) gets converted to 2020-07-16T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: @Bipin sorry i posted the wrong code.. i use this piece of code if i want the time to always be 00:00. I updated the snippet (instead of using date.getfullyear, getfullmonth, getdate i simply get the full time of the date). Try it out and tell me how it works

Comment: now i m getting problem in displaying values like 1970-01-01T14:00:00.000+0000 returning from backend api but now it shows 19:30
i m formatting date by below function to display it

export function formatTime(date) {
    const time = new Date(date);
    return time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes();
}

Comment: you shouldn't use the "fixTimezoneOffset" function when displaying dates from your backend in your react app.

Comment: I think there will be solution for this

Comment: If we find a solution in react-datepicker then no need to parse it so if you have any solution please suggest me in react-datepicker component . Thanks @Tim gerhard

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your datepicker. It's the way javascript handles dates.

Comment: In previous project i had used material ui datepicker but it was working fine there was not an issue in date but in current project i had to use react-datepicker

Comment: I need some other solution for this problem

Comment: @Bipin this is acutally a different question but i highly suggest you try understanding how javascript dates work. This datestring: 1970-01-01T14:00:00.000+0000 contains a date and time. This time is for UTC+00. If you have a different timezone (you have GMT+0530) your string would have to look like this: 1970-01-01T14:00:00.000+0530. Your browser / client automatically shows you the date/time string in your locale. in my case it always shows date & time in gmt+0100.